# Net Core: Type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating a project from .Net 4.6.2 into .Net Core 2.0. 
What is the replacement for GlobalFilterCollection in Net Core?

```
The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    HPE.Kruta.Web.Core  


    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you would explicitly need to add the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` in your project. Follow these steps:

In your project, under `Dependencies` in your solution explorer, right click and choose `Add Reference` option. Then under the `Reference Manager` window, click on Browse.

Then navigate where your ASP .NET is installed. It should be here:

**Program files(x86) --> Microsoft ASP.NET --> ASP.NET MVC 4.6 --> Assemblies---> System.Web.Mvc.dll**

Include this file in your Assemblies in your project. Once you include this .dll file, simply import `using System.Web.Mvc;` and then you would be able to use `GlobalFilterCollection filters` in your project.

**EDIT**:

In .NET CORE, the way your register your filters has changed. I will just show you a small example on how you can register a filter.

As per official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution):

> You can register a filter globally (for all controllers and actions) by adding it to the MvcOptions.Filters collection in the  ConfigureServices method in the Startup class

For example: If I want to use AuthorizeAttribute, I cannot add `AuthorizeAttribute` into `MvcOptions.Filters`. I would need to create an `AuthorizationPolicy` and use `AuthorizeFilter`.

```
var authorizepolicy= new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin", "SuperUser")
        .Build();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizepolicy));
});
```

Comment: so whats the equivalent of GlobalCollectionFilter? you wrote it for authorizationpolicy